# SELECT DISTINCT with field type 'text' and SUM(amt)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-express

I'm having trouble with a SQL query:

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT *, SUM(amt) AS ttl_amt FROM table WHERE..."
```

Two of my fields are of type 'text', SQL does not allow for this type to be selected as DISTINCT as they are not comparable.

I need to group relative items and display them as a single row with a combined `ttl_amt` value as seen above.

I've tried selecting the 'non-text' fields (varchar, float, int, etc) in the `SELECT DISTINCT` statement and then pulling the 'text' fields in a `while()` loop using another SQL query but that information does not show up (the 'text' fields).

If you need more information let me know.

Any ideas? I'm not an expert when it comes to SQL syntax.

Comment: I heard something about using `CREATE VIEW` in my SQL statement but I'm not sure what the yield would be.. I'm also unsure about how to use it.

Comment: Looks like you actually want `select field1, ..., fieldN, sum(amt) from table group by field1, ..., fieldN`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko SQL says 'text data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.'

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, SQLite?

Comment: @Barmar I'm using SQL-Server Express

Comment: Why are you storing numerical data in a text field?

Comment: @proPhet: it seems that instead of CHAR/VARCHAR (string equivalents) you're using TEXT/CLOB which are not string compartible and represent raw data (raw text). Change field(s) type to varchar or exclude it(them) form select and group by

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not, the `amt` field is of type 'float'.. I have two other fields that are of type 'text'

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks, will give it a go.. I'm only worried 'VARCHAR' won't be able to store enough data, hence the reason I used 'TEXT'. The fields hold descriptions that can be anywhere from 5 to 5000 characters I'd imagine

Comment: @proPhet: What RDBMS so you use? If MS SQL, VarChar can can hold up to 8000 characters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx if MySQL, than even more: 65535.

Comment: Got it.  I see from the other comments that your problem comes from using a TEXT field where VARCHAR would have the characteristics you need for this operation.  That sounds right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using *aggregate functions* like `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, `AVG()` etc. all the outher fields within `SELECT` section should be either within *aggregate functions* or should be mentioned in `GROUP BY`.
It seems that you actually want SQL being something like that:

```
  select Field1, -- you can't use * here!
         Field2,
         ...
         FieldN,
         Sum(amt)
    from Table
group by Field1, -- you can't use * here!
         Field2,
         ...
         FieldN
```

`group by` makes the grouping distinct, so you don't need any additional `DISTINCT` here

Comment: I tried that now and SQL says 'text data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.'

Comment: The problem is my two 'text' type data fields

Comment: @proPhet: `Text` is not a string (which you can compare, sort etc.) its a kind of LOB (Large OBject) and represents raw data. Since you can't compare LOB's you can't group by them. Change fields' type to VarChar or (better), remove them from both `select` and `group by`

Comment: I tired that too, and then tried to pull the LOB fields in the `while()` loop, but the LOB data did not show

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use group by statement instead of distinct? for example:

Select field1,field2,field3, sum(field4) from table where ... group by field1,field2,field3;

regards

Comment: I tried that now but SQL says 'text data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.'

Answer (score 2):

you are correct: The Text-Datatype is not allowed in any grouping. try it via convert

e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(max),amt) AS ttl_amt FROM table WHERE 1=1
```

(The * Shouldnt be used in a distinct)

Edit: SUM on a varcharfield was a stupid idea, sorry. Corrected